# gradually introducing ngx-leaflet into an app with extensive leaflet use

Tags: angular, ngx-leaflet

I am developing in a large angular 8 app that has many components that use leaflet. The existing components use leaflet and some plugins directly, imported like so:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet'
import 'leaflet.markercluster'
```

which has been working.

I'd like to gradually introduce `ngx-leaflet` as we build out new components and refactor existing ones, but this is causing trouble. I created a simple map component following the documentation, which seems to work fine. However, existing components are now failing to render properly. A component using markercluster errors with 
`TypeError: L.MarkerClusterGroup is not a constructor`.
The `L` object that the component is trying to use appears to be properly extended with the markercluster functionality, but down the callstack I see

```
runOutsideAngular   @   core.js:39571
```

, which I suspect is stemming from some cross communication with `ngx-leaflet`.

I haven't seen any examples or documentation trying to do what I'm describing- is it expected that leaflet used outside of the `ngx-leaflet` directives will be problematic like this, or should I be able to isolate the library to the components that I'm intending to use it in?

Answer (score 0):

`runOutsideAngular` was a red herring, the root cause was an improperly packaged plugin (Leaflet.FreeDraw). ngx-leaflet appears to work fine alongside other usages of leaflet.